# search a word inside a pdf in terminal linux without any app

Tags: linux, shell, file, pdf, binary-data

Is it possible to use `grep` or other command and/or `regex` in order to search for a particular pattern within a PDF file?

Comment: This may help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6704/how-can-i-grep-in-pdf-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the `pdftotext` utility installed, you can use the following command to search through the text of a PDF file:

```
pdftotext myfile.pdf - | grep 'pattern'
```

You have to use some utility (such as `pdftotext`) to convert the PDF file to text before feeding it into `grep` (otherwise `grep` would have a hard time making sense out of the raw PDF file), but any utility that does this should  work.

On Ubuntu and Debian, `pdftotext` is part of the `poppler-utils` package.

Comment: What do you mean by "a direct way"...?

Comment: @Frxstrem : i dont want to use any app ! directly access to PDFs content !

Comment: @Scony : this command havnt a valid result ! i want read extract the words and patterns !

Answer (score 2):

try with:

```
cat file.pdf | strings | grep 'pattern'
```

Answer (score 1):

Short: yes (use the flag `-b` for *binary files*).

But chances are high you will **not** find what you are looking for. PDF files are usually binary, compressed, and heavily encoded at that -- up to the point not even Acrobat Reader can copy sensible text out of it.

Comment: mmm... yes thanks for your answer ! im agree !and i think if it was possible there wasnt any need to applications ! but any way ,i ask my question !